# Javascript - Why does the JavaScript I wrote inside a TypeScript file not function correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have an ionic project that I created. I added JavaScript code inside the type script of the ionic project, but I found that the function is not working.

`problem.html`

```
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-7 style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="center-block">
      <!--<input type="file" id="view" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple">-->
      <!--<input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" onchange="document.getElementById('blah').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">-->
      <article>
        <input id="files" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple/>
        <button ion-button (click)="imageUpload()"> Here ! </button>
      </article>
    </div>
  </ion-col>

 <p style="text-align:center;">
    <output id="result">
      <div>
      </div>
    </output>
```

Inside my problem.ts file:

```
imageUpload(){

  window.onload = function () {
console.log("hihi");
    //Check File API support zzzz
    (<any>$('#files')).live("change", function (event) {
      var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
      var output = document.getElementById("result");
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        //Only pics
        // if(!file.type.match('image'))
        if (file.type.match('image.*')) {
          if (this.files[0].size < 2097152) {
            // continue;
            var picReader = new FileReader();
            picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
              var picFile = <FileReader>event.target;
              var div = document.createElement("div");
              div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                "title='preview image'>";
              output.insertBefore(div, null);
            });
            //Read the image
            $('#clear, #result').show();
            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
          } else {
            alert("Image Size is too big. Minimum size is 2MB.");
            $(this).val("");
          }
        } else {
          alert("You can only upload image file.");
          $(this).val("");
        }
      }
    });
    (<any>$('#files')).live("click", function () {
      $('.thumbnail').parent().remove();
      $('result').hide();
      $(this).val("");
    });

    (<any>$('#clear')).live("click", function () {
      $('.thumbnail').parent().remove();
      $('#result').hide();
      $('#files').val("");
      $(this).hide();
    });

  }
}
```

This is all of my code. After I implemented it, no errors were returned, but I found that my JavaScript, the `imageUpload()` function specifically, is not working. I `console.log` and nothing is returned in my console.

Anyone know what the problem is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing to check is, do you have a valid window object when this method is called? Is window.onLoad() ever called? I don't remember ever using window.onLoad() in an ionic app.

Where is this method imageUpload() called? I'll probably get a hold of a valid window object first (e.g., in a component or service), and pass it into this method. And, I'd suggest changing your code so that your "onload" function is called within one of the Angular/Ionic component lifecycle methods. The way your code looks, I doubt that it'll ever run in an Angular/Ionic app.

Comment: Ya..I have checked and console.log() it the windown.onload() is not called..I am new to ionic, and they told that everything that work in Java is going to work in typescript. But I don't know why the window.onload is not working. Do you know what to replace window.onload ??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the imageUpload() function is called when I clicked the button. How to edit it so that it will works in my application ??